# The copyright part in a file

Tags: licensing, copyright-display

My project is contributed under the **GPL** lisence. I want to add some copyright notices into all files. Would it be enough:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Developer Name 1, Developer Name 2
 * This file is part of %Project name% (page at https://page).
 * Project is contributed with GPL license. For more information, visit web page.
 */
```

Or I have to include some license text there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to distribute code under the GPL, then have a look at the [GNU Hello](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/) program for examples of how to decorate your source code with appropriate comments.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinary boilerplate for the GNU GPL reads as follows, and that is what you should use.

> Copyright (C) [years] [name of copyright holder]
>
> This program is free software; you can
>   redistribute it and/or modify it under
>   the terms of the GNU General Public
>   License as published by the Free
>   Software Foundation; either version 3
>   of the License, or (at your option)
>   any later version.
>
> This program is distributed in the
>   hope that it will be useful, but
>   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
>   implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See
>   the GNU General Public License for
>   more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the
>   GNU General Public License along with
>   this program; if not, see
>   http://www.gnu.org/licenses.

(From the [GPL FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html))